# Nested SELECT with a WHERE clause in Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have a problem with running a Spark SQL query which uses a nested select with a "where in" clause. In the query below *table1* represents a temporary table which comes from a more complicated query. In the end I want to substitute *table1* with this query.

```
select * from (select * from table1) as table2 
where (product, price) 
in (select product, min(price) from table2 group by product)
```

The Spark error I get says:

> AnalysisException: 'Table or view not found: table2;

How could I possibly change the query to make it work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

`subquery` (i.e. `(select * from table1) as table2` ) is not needed & it is limited to immediate use after `subquery` defined you can't use with `in` or `where` clause, you can use `correlated` subquery instead :

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 
where t1.price = (select min(t2.price) from table1 t2 where t2.product = t1.product);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem since you are referring to the table1 twice. Maybe I was not clear enough, I want to substitute table1 with another query that's why I want to avoid calling it twice. I'll update my question.